# Is there a prop to hide the tooltip in MUI DataGrid?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

With MUI v5 a tooltip was added to the DataGrid cells. I'm looking for a way to disable all of the tooltips without creating a custom render for each column.

I've tried `disableTooltips` and `tooltipShowDelay={0}` but those did not disable the tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it but its not optimal to say the least.

you can use **renderCell** (just know it can effect rendering speed)

```
<DataGrid
  columns={[{ field: 'name',headerName: 'name',renderCell:(params)=><span>{params.value}</span> }]}
  rows={rows.data}
/>
```

Comment: Yep, that's what we're currently doing. I was just hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to disable the title attribute of the MUI `cellContent` in `DataGridPro`. While the `renderCell` approach can indeed achieve this, here's a **CSS-based** solution that might be more convenient and efficient:

```
<DataGridPro rows={...} columns={...}
sx={{
      '& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover': {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
      '.MuiDataGrid-cellContent': {
        pointerEvents: 'none',
      },
    }} />
```

**Explanation:**

- This CSS rule targets the `.MuiDataGrid-cellContent` class, which styles the inner content area of each cell in `DataGridPro`.
- By setting `pointerEvents: 'none'`, we effectively disable any interactive behaviors (like hover states or tooltips) that might trigger the title attribute. This includes potential accessibility concerns caused by hidden attributes. If you want the cell to have cursor (as in the code snippet), you can add `cursor: 'pointer'`.